# Значение слова sic в приведенном ниже контексте

Tags: синтаксис, лексика, морфология

О каких ошибках( на которые указывает слово sic) в данном контексте идёт речь?

Гости, как выяснилось (к огромному удивлению хозяев — представьте себе, да), не говорят ни слова по-французски, и, помимо трат денежных, оказалось, что требуется тратить столь драгоценное для каждого француза свое **(sic!)** свободное время, чтобы решать чужие проблемы **(re-sic!)** совершенно посторонних и очень чужих **(re-re-sic!)** людей. С которыми "нет и не может быть ничего общего".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Sic!* не указывает на ошибки, это слово ставится после того слова или словосочетания, которое автор хочет особо подчеркнуть, на которое хочет обратить особое внимание читателей.

Comment: Не обязательно (ошибка). Порой как раз наоборот - предостерегают читателя, чтобы он не расценил написанное как ошибку или описку, а верил своим глазам. По сему лучший способ смысловой передачи этого "sic" - "верь написанному", "именно так". Оба случая употребления - частный случай общего значения - верификация, подтверждение автором написанного как написанного им верно, без описки (Если в цитате содержится ошибка, автор этим "sic" переадресует ошибку автору цитаты)..https://pishu-pravilno.livejournal.com/1251802.html